# Set a Specific Width for An Article Text Area

Tags: html, css

```
        <div id="textcontent">
            <center>
            <br /><p>........... ARTICLE IN HERE .........</p>
            </center>
        </div>


#textcontent {  
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#textcontent p {    
    margin-right: -24px;
    width: 663px;
}
```

ARTICLE IN HERE will display an article posted by user.

**Snapshot:**

[image]

**Problem:**

A line of an article by pass the side boundries. How can i set specific fixed width so the text gets indented (moved to second line) automatically and doesn't pass the side borders?

*Note:* text area height gets expanded automatically as lines of text increase.

**Extra Info:**

```
<div id="posted_wrap">
        <div id="posted_middle">
            <div id="posted_top"></div>         
                   <div id="textcontent">
                   <center>
                      <br /><p><?php echo $thread; ?></p>
                   </center>
                </div>
            <br />
            <div id="posted_bottom"></div>
       </div></div>
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's-what with the small snippet of CSS you've provided, but from seeing the markup it looks over-engineered, a much simpler solution would probably work - but I have no idea what your problem is. Even the image does not display a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#textcontent p {
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
width: 663px;
```

Remove `<center>` as it's not needed, and is deprecated. Set your margin of your paragraph tag to have auto (left and right).

That code works. The code you posted works too - so you may have a positioning or float issue going on above the code you're struggling with.

If those black "chalk" lines are a background image you can add:
`padding:0 10px` (for example) to your `<p>` tag to keep the text inside further from the edges.